# MySQL ORDER BY Datetime works in PHPMyAdmin but not PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this query in PHPMyAdmin

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE start_datetime > CURDATE() ORDER BY start_datetime ASC;
```

I get this result

2019-08-19 07:30:00

2020-03-21 06:30:00

2020-04-30 07:30:00

2020-07-30 07:30:00

Although when I run the query on my website, the order returned is in the order that the rows were written to the table.

2020-07-30 07:30:00

2020-05-02 07:30:00

2020-04-30 07:30:00

2020-03-21 06:30:00

2019-08-19 07:30:00

Original PHP:

```html
$search = "%" . $search . "%";
echo "The sort type is: " . $sortType . "<br>";
// fetch events 
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE LOWER(event_name) LIKE LOWER(?) AND start_datetime > CURDATE() ORDER BY ? ASC;");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $search, $sortType);
$stmt->execute();
$eventResult = $stmt->get_result();
if (isset($stmt->errno)) {
 if ($stmt->errno != 0) {
  echo "An error occured! Error Number: " . $stmt->errno . "<br> Error message: " . $stmt->error;
 }
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Can you add the PHP code you use for this result?

Comment: replace your images with plain text

Comment: You cannot bind column names. Your Order By will not work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try an alternative method

Comment: you can not do `ORDER BY ?` with prepared statement. Prepared statements does not work when you put column names through parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` bind placeholder is in the place of a *value* in the SQL statement. It is not an identifier. When a value is bound, and the statement is executed, the question mark gets replaced with a *value*.

The result is as if we had done this:

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM tbl_events e
 WHERE e.start_datetime > CURDATE() 
 ORDER BY 'start_datetime' ASC;
          ^              ^
```

Note the single quotes. That's a string literal, a value. Not a reference to a column. It doesn't matter what value we pass in, it's going to be the same for every row.

To get the ordering to be on a column, based on a value passed in, we could do something like this:

```
 ORDER 
    BY CASE ?
         WHEN 'start_datetime'  THEN e.start_datetime
         WHEN 'something_else'  THEN someothervalidexpression
       END
       ASC
```